# Angular - 2 way data binding with DIV element style

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm building a dragging interface using Angular and jQueryUI. The reason I want to use Angular is, I wanted angularJS 2 way data binding which is really awesome!

Here is the codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmuvH/

In the codepen - you will see there is box with text - "hello everyone" (div#layer). I did bind its style with angular -

```
top:{{layer.data.top}}px;left: {{layer.data.left}}px
```

And added two input fields which also have **ng-model** to that same **layer.data.top** and **layer.data.left**;
So when you change the value in the input field - it will move the div element. So far this works great.

But I also made that "hello everyone" div draggable using jqueryUI in angular directive. So you can drag that element around.

What I want now is - If I drag around the "hello everyone" div element - it will also update **layer.data.left** and **layer.data.top**. 
So this will also change the value in the input field. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of 2 answers, I ended up using following update -

I just updated my code in drag event function -

```
drag: function( event, ui ) 
{
    scope.layer.data.left = ui.position.left;
    scope.layer.data.top = ui.position.top;
    scope.$apply();
}
```

Here is the updated codepen - 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgzme

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
Top : <input id='top' type="text" ng-model="layer.data.top">
Left : <input id='left' type="text" ng-model="layer.data.left">
```

assign specific ids to both inputs, then do this in your `drag` function:

```
drag: function( event, ui ) {
   console.log(event);
   $('#top').val($(this).position().top);
   $('#left').val($(this).position().left);
}
```

#### [Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CwclH/)

Comment: You did put me in right track, but changing input field value by selecting dom element - doesn't feel like angular way!

Instead I just updated my data by changing actual data source - 
`layer.data.top = ui.position.left`.
And then use `$scope.$apply()`

Answer (score 1):

you can add an event listener for `mouseup` on the layer div, it calls a function that changes the layer data accordingly,
so it will be:

1- inside your controller define a function like this:

```
$scope.getInfo = function (layer) {
  var el = document.getElementById('layer');
  layer.data.left = parseInt(el.style["left"]);
  layer.data.top = parseInt(el.style["top"]);
}
```

2- add  `ng-mouseup="getInfo(layer)"` to your layer div

here's an updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/labibismaiel/pen/vhwaF)

Comment: That is a good idea but strangely when I change the value of 'layer.data.left' & 'layer.data.top' in this way - it doesn't update the input field value! Any idea why?

Comment: Aha.. got it - just needed to use $scope.$apply()

Comment: check the codepen I provided, and you won't need a $scope.$apply()